# Reducing width of bar chart series

Tags: apache-flex, charts

*Note: by `width` i mean the height here, I use width because by default, bar charts are vertical and flex uses the width property*

I want to reduce the width of the following barchart so Type 5, Type 4, Type 3, Type 2, Type 1 are very close to each other. I tried playing with the `barWidthRatio`, the `horizontalAxisRatio` and the `maxBarWidth` properties. Neither is giving me the desired result. I can only manage to reduce the width of the orange bars, how do I reduce the width of the blue bars?

[image]

Is there no way to do this?

Comment: What blue bars? Are you referring to the grayish lines that are part of the axes by chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im pretty sure your going to have to reduce the height of the whole chart to do that, or the container that contains the chart. The chart is probably set to height=100%, so it will always stretch out those blue bars